# Getting crash when changing permission

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-permissions

A very unusual error has occurred with me, never experienced such a thing.

I am using fragments in my application. In android M and above I am using the app, when I minimize the application and grant the permission and again resume the application, the app crashes as I am trying to use an object in main activity but that I get null. But when I do the same and I remove a permission I do not get a crash.

It only happens when I try to grants the permission when the application is minimized. If I close the application and grant the permission and again start the application then I don't face any such issue.

Line on which i get error :

```
Screen_title.setText("Survey No. " + mainActivity.currentTask.farmerData.farms.survey_number);
```

where  "mainActivity.currentTask" is null.

Logcat :

```
04-13 10:44:26.226 16742-16742/com.app.farmtrace.fieldagent E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.app.farmtrace.fieldagent, PID: 16742 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.app.farmtrace.fieldagent/com.app.farmtrace.fieldagent.Activity.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'com.app.farmtrace.fieldagent.Data.Farmer_Data.FarmerData com.app.farmtrace.fieldagent.Data.Task.farmerData' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3256)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3352)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:223)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1797)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7231)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'com.app.farmtrace.fieldagent.Data.Farmer_Data.FarmerData com.app.farmtrace.fieldagent.Data.Task.farmerData' on a null object reference
    at com.app.farmtrace.fieldagent.Fragment.Farmer_Details.bindView(Farmer_Details.java:88)
    at com.app.farmtrace.fieldagent.Fragment.Farmer_Details.onViewCreated(Farmer_Details.java:64)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1315)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1523)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1585)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:2832)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:201)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:603)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:181)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1266)
    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6916)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3219)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3352) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:223) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1797) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7231) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Comment: What does your logcat says?

Comment: nullpointer exception on the context object, but when i just minimize and resume on the same page without changing permission i dont get the crash

Comment: provide your logcat

Comment: can you post your code for the permission

Comment: @Parth Anjaria just replace `getContext()` or Context Object to `getActivity()`

Comment: Can you show your full code. I do believe your object is null, or maybe the variable within the object is null.

Answer (score 0):

we cant give permission when application is running in background that's why your application is crashing. when application runs in background , system already occupied some resources for it , so we cant cahnge its permission when app is running in background .

Comment: does this crash happen in other applications too?

Comment: as you know that from android M , they increase app security by providing runtime app permission . So every application in android M which requires runtime permission , would be facing same issue.

Comment: @Tej please note that we can give and revoke permissions while the app is not in foreground. "The user can revoke the permissions at any time, by going to the app's Settings screen." https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: Yes facing issue when i change permissions from settings screen

Answer (score 0):

```
private Context mContext;
 private HomeTab mActivity;

 mActivity = ((HomeTab) getActivity());
 mContext = ((HomeTab) getContext());
```

Check permission in fragment  like below pass your activity and context

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(),
            android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
            ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(),
                    android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(),
                new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                        android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                REQUEST_LOCATION);
    } else {
        Log.e("DB", "PERMISSION GRANTED");
    }
```